# How to pass request object from one serializer class to other serializer class in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to access userId of current logged-in user. for that i need to pass the request object from one serialiser to another. Here's my code

```
class ThreadViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
op = PostDetailViewSerializer(context={'request': request})

class Meta:
    model = Thread
    fields = ('id', 'title', 'op', 'group_id', 'type', 'reference_id', 'is_frozen', 'views', 'is_pinned')
```

In PostDetailViewSerializer, I want to pass request object but for that it requires self object. like this

```
request = self.context.get('request')
```

Thus, How can we pass the request object to PostDetailViewSerializer class in ThreadViewSerializer class. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two ways of achieving that:

1. You can use a `SerializerMethodField` to access the `self.context` (keep in mind that this a read-only serializer):

```py
class ThreadViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    op = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_op(self, instance):
        return PostDetailViewSerializer(instance=instance.op, context=self.context).data

    class Meta:
        model = Thread
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'op', 'group_id', 'type', 'reference_id', 'is_frozen', 'views', 'is_pinned')
```

2. You can override the `__init__` method of your `ThreadViewSerializer` and pass the context then down to your fields:

```py
class ThreadViewSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['op'] = PostDetailViewSerializer(context=self.context)

    class Meta:
        model = Thread
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'op', 'group_id', 'type', 'reference_id', 'is_frozen', 'views', 'is_pinned')
```

Comment: Can I know from where I can learn Django in that much detail. Any resources suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: Hey, @VishalKumar, I think the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/) are usually a great resource to use, but the thing I give as advice to everyone who's starting/trying to get a deeper understanding of DRF specially: [read through their code](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/tree/master/rest_framework)! it is very accessible and straightforward (with pretty good comment coverage where needed as well). There are websites like [Classy DRF](https://www.cdrf.co/) that provide an ever easier way to navigate around the views/serializer classes. Good luck! :)